# How can I find a single patch covering the whole cylinder?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I want to show that the cylinder $C:=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2=1\}$ can be covered by a single surface patch.

We have the following definition:

> A surface patch is a map $\sigma: U\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^3$, where $U \subset \mathbb R^2$ is open and $\sigma:U\rightarrow \sigma(U)$ is a smooth homeomorphism such that $d\sigma$ is injective.

My idea is the following:

Let me define $$\sigma:(0,1)\times \Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^3;~~(x,z)\mapsto (x,\sqrt{1-x^2},z)$$
Then since in all derivatives of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ we only have a term of the form $(1-x^2)^{...}$ in the denominator, we deduce that $\sigma$ is smooth. Furthermore $$d\sigma= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  $$ Then if we consider $$A:=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  $$then $\det(M)=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ so $\det(M)=0$ iff $x=0$ but since $0$ is excluded we deduce that $d\sigma$ is injective. Now to conclude remark that $\sigma$ is continuous and $\sigma^{-1}(x,y,z)=(\sqrt{1-y^2},z)$ for all $(x,y,z)\in C$. But since $\sigma^{-1}$ is also continuous we deduce that $\sigma$ is a homeomorphism and thus we conclude that $\sigma$ is a surface patch of $C$.

Does this work?

Comment: How have you addressed the actual question, though? Does your patch cover the whole surface? Is this even possible?

Comment: @TedShifrin I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately your function is not onto. The point $(1,0,0)$ is not contained in the image.

Try $U = \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$ and
$\sigma(p) = (p/\lVert p \rVert,(\lVert p \rVert^2-1)/\lVert p \rVert)$.